# Hide frame on minimise but show again on click

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I'm hiding the frame like this when the user clicks the minimize button:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_ICONIZE, self.onMinimize)

def onMinimize(self, event):
    self.Show(False)
```

Then when the user clicks the tray icon I unhide it:

```
def on_left_down(self, event):
    print 'Tray icon was left-clicked.'
    if not frame.IsShown():
        jsExternal = JavascriptExternal(frame.browser)
        jsExternal.refreshWindow()
        frame.Show()
    else:
        frame.Show(False)
```

This all works, but only frame opens up minimized when clicking the tray icon. How would I open the window not minimized?

Comment: Perhaps its much easier just showing a close button, is this even possible?

Comment: Ok, got it working to only show the close button

Answer (score 0):

You might need to call the frame's Raise() method to get it out of its minimized state. Also if you are binding to EVT_CLOSE to minimize to tray, then when you actually want to close the application, you'll need to Destroy() it as the Close() method will just keep hiding it. See the following articles:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/07/12/wxpython-how-to-minimize-to-system-tray/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/12/13/wxpython-101-creating-taskbar-icons/